# Select all checkbox for each item on a list and update visually xaml using xamarin forms and syncfusion

Tags: listview, checkbox, xamarin.forms, uicollectionview, syncfusion

I have a very complicated collection view of items and I would like to have the option to select all or select by skipping items from the binding list. Visually the first select all option is outside of the list. How can I select each item from the list and obtain its properties for example item id?

What I want
[image]

XAML

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="editview" Grid.Row="3" IsVisible="false">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ListData}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding subject}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding body}"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       VerticalOptions="End" />
             <syncfusion:SfCheckBox x:Name="_checkbox"  IsThreeState="True" StateChanged="CheckBox_StateChanged" CornerRadius="5.0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
  </StackLayout>
```

C#

```
void SelectAll_StateChanged(System.Object sender, Syncfusion.XForms.Buttons.StateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!skip)
            {
                skip = true;
                New_ListData = vm.ListData;
                foreach (var item in New_ListData)
                {
                  NOTE: I DONT HAVE ACCESS TO _checkbox INSIDE THIS. I DONT KNOW WHY?
                  _checkbox.IsChecked = e.IsChecked;
                }
```

//THEN UPDATE THE COLLECTION VIEW WITH ALL CHECKBOXES TO TRUE

```
                 skip = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: sender argument is CheckBox. `(CheckBox)sender.IsChecked =  e.IsChecked ` something like this. And as for item id `((CheckBox))sender.BindingContext` will give you the model the current item is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used a checkbox inside the DataTemplate, it not possible to get it directly in code behind. By performing the binding with checkbox IsChecked property, you can achieve your requirement.

We have prepared a sample like this requirement, it will be downloaded from the below link.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Checklist-866762270.zip